# compare two input values (voting system) python

Tags: python, integer

```
name1 = {}
name2 = {}
result = {}
while True:
    response = input("who do you want to vote on?")
    if name1:
        name1 += 1
    if name2:
        name2 += 1
    if response == 'finished':

        print(result, "has won")
        break
```

I'm currently trying to count values together, and print the winning name when "finished" has been typed in. I tried to use greater then `>` and less then `<` but then I get a error saying input is an int (number).

Comment: `name1` and `name2` are dicts. You can't use `+=1` on a dict.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a modified version of your code that I think solves what you were trying to do

```
names = ['foo', 'bar']
counts = [0, 0]
while True:
    response = input("who do you want to vote on? ")
    if response == names[0]:
        counts[0] += 1
    elif response == names[1]:
        counts[1] += 1
        
    if response == 'finished':
        if counts[0] == counts[1]:
            print('tie')
        elif counts[0] > counts[1]:
            print(names[0], 'has won')
        else:
            print(names[1], 'has won')
        break
```

A couple example runs

```
who do you want to vote on? foo
who do you want to vote on? foo
who do you want to vote on? bar
who do you want to vote on? finished
foo has won
```

and

```
who do you want to vote on? foo
who do you want to vote on? bar
who do you want to vote on? finished
tie
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, how does the count [0,0] get the position of foo and bar?

Comment: it doesn't, for simplicity i just chose to make them the same length and indices. instead you could either use a `dict` to map the key to the count or use `names.index('foo')` to find the index to use in `counts` for example

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using a dictionary for storing the counts:

```
names={'name1':0,'name2':0}

while True:
    response = input("who do you want to vote on?")
    if response == 'finished':
        if len(set(names.values()))==1:
            print('Both candidates are tied.')
            break
        print(max(names, key=names.get), "has won.")
        break
    try:
        names[response]+=1
    except KeyError:
        print(f"{response} is no candidate.")
```

Sample output:

```
who do you want to vote on?name1

who do you want to vote on?name2

who do you want to vote on?finished
Both players are tied.
```

Or:

```
who do you want to vote on?name1

who do you want to vote on?finished
name1 has won.
```